# MEMO N/A after submitting to bridge endpoint /builder

Tags: horizon, payments, memo, bridge-server

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8006/builder \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "source": "GBJ6ONYK73A65BRW7SOGQYEDCN55NCYDH5WJTE7WZIZXF3RRX2GFI33T",
    "memo": {
      "text": "qwerty12345"
    },
    "operations": [
        {
            "type": "payment",
            "body":{
                "source":"GBJ6ONYK73A65BRW7SOGQYEDCN55NCYDH5WJTE7WZIZXF3RRX2GFI33T",
                "destination":"GCZC5EG7BURORGG46B67FDBZDTWKQ5G6GLHWU6K535222ELH63MNKOT7",
                "amount": "1000"
            }
        }   
    ],  
    "signers": ["*************************************"]
}
```

After doing this though my destination account got credited, while looking up the explorer it shows Memo N/A.

1. What could possibly be wrong here?
2. What can be done to fix this?

Hoping for answers!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it often helps to debug these problems by cross-checking tools against one another, so you might check out https://github.com/xdrpp/stc which will let you see what transactions you are actually building without having to submit them to the network.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this instead:

`"memo_type":"text","memo":"qwerty12345"`

Comment: i did try that ! But didn't help either. The transaction envelope that i got from submitting this transaction to /builder shows memoNone.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough it doesn't look like the builder endpoint reads the memo from the request: https://github.com/stellar/bridge-server/blob/master/src/github.com/stellar/gateway/bridge/handlers/request_handler_builder.go

Maybe this is a bug in the bridge server, or an intentional omission?

Comment: I think they've omitted it; looking at the request_handler_builder. But why could they've omitted it? Any ideas?

Comment: Probably just missed it when it was implemented. Looks like payments support it so there's no reason I can think of that /builder does not.

Comment: Yep! Payment supports memo and works all fine ! Was jus wondering why they haven’t implemented it in /builder ?!